# PHP run file automatically every 5 minutes without page load

Tags: php

Hi i want to run my php file every 5 minutes without page load using ajax. also so content based on fromtime to totime

```
require_once("config.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule where status='1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Content: " . $row["content"] . "<br />";
        echo "Content: " . $row["fromtime"] . "<br />";     
        echo $date = time();
        $test = strtotime($row["fromtime"]);
        echo "<br />";          
        echo $test;
        if ($date > $test) {
            echo "Success";
        }
        else {
            echo "Fail";
        }

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: _"i want to run my php file every 5 minutes without page load using ajax"_ - What is your question/issue? Currently, it's just a statement.

Comment: run cron for same

Comment: i have to show content based on timing. i have already stored data with show and close time. that specific time without page load content have to show

Comment: That still doesn't tell us what your _issue_ is. Where are you stuck? You already mentioned Ajax. Where is that code? What does/doesn't work? What are you asking us to help you with? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `AJAX` implies Javascript of which I see none.  I mean it is part of the name  Asynchronous Javascipt And Xml (even though no one uses XML) ... anyway AJAJ sounds stupid. Asynchronous Javascipt And Javascript Object Notation, but then we are mixing acronyms (AJAX and JSON) and incosistant ones at that (J vs JS for javasciprt), but I digress.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have server access you'll need to set up a `crontab`. For every 5 mins it'll be

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/php/script.php
```

Noticed updated for Ajax. Use this solution if you want to run it without the page being open.

Also noticed you want to parse variables, php does support that and parsing them in is like so:

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/php/script.php var1 var2
```

Comment: Even if this might be a better solution in theory, we simply have no idea at this time. We should wait to write answers until the OP actually gives us more information or we're simply just guessing.  We don't even know what OS the OP is running this on or if it should run in the background at all.

Comment: I agree, however, this should at least give him what to google if it's Windows. Mac uses crontab too if I recollect.

Comment: Well, since we don't even know if this should be run in the background, or if it is for the user, the question is still _way_ too unclear to be answered at all.